# How to know which nodes in a graph are removable

Tags: r, algorithm, graph-theory, igraph

I have a graph `g` of approx 200 vertex with some attributes, I would like to know which nodes can be removed, i.e, which means `g` is still a connected sub-network after removing them and also I would like to know which node will produce the highest increase in the attributes I need.

Here is an example that maybe is more understandable

```
g <- erdos.renyi.game(200, 0.03)
V(g)$name <- 1:vcount(my_graph) 
V(g)$weight <- rnorm(200) 
V(g)$RWRNodeweight <- runif(200, min=0, max=0.05)

#Criteria to meet
cumsum <- sum(V(g)$weight*V(g)$RWRNodeweight)/sqrt(sum(V(g)$RWRNodeweight^2))
```

I would like to know which nodes are "removable", i.e, after removing them the graph is still fully connected and then if removing a "removable" node `cumsum` increases, remove the one with the largest increase. Once the "removable" node with the highest increase is removed I want to start again the procedure until there in no increase in `cumsum` when a "removable" node is removed

Comment: Algorithm question... check the other SE sites.

Comment: What attributes do you nodes have? You could run a DFS or BFS after the node is removed, to check if the number of nodes reached is `|V(g)|-(n+1)|`, where n is the number of removed nodes.

Comment: @MarcoGetrost, my nodes have two attributes, `weight` and `RWRnodeweight`, which are used to calculate `cumsum`

Comment: @user2380782 how do you know which nodes are connected? you must store this information somehow?

Comment: @MarcoGetrost, the graph is fully connected, i.e, all the nodes are connected. I don't have the information about connectivity stored in any node attribute but I suppose I could create a attribute like `sapply(V(my_graph), function(x) is.connected(delete.vertices(my_graph, x))` -> V(my_graph)$removable

Comment: @user2380782 The problem is, if you have no inforomation about the Arcs/Edges of the graph, it will be impossible to determine if the graph is still connected once a node/vertex is removed. So you will need to either store information of the arcs/edges somewhere or in each vertex store information about the outgoing arcs/edges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know which nodes are "removable", i.e, after removing them the graph is still fully connected

[`articulation.points`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/igraph/docs/articulation.points) tells you the list of nodes whose removal would increase the number of connected components. Any node that is *not* in this list is safe to remove. Then you have to loop over this list and calculate the new value of `cumsum` (excluding each of the nodes one by one) to find which one is the best to remove.

Comment: thanks @Tamas for the answer, `articulation.points` gives me an excellent start point

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate [spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree) and then you can remove nodes at end (nodes with single vertices) until you reach single node if required.